# Now the position in a table and open a jpanel

Tags: java, swing, position

I’m programing in Java Netbeans and I'm making an application for a touch screen.
I have a table, I would like if it’s possible to click in a cell of the table and go to another jpanel?
Look the example:

[image: table example]

If a click in the John’s line and the Form complete column, I need to open the jpanel where is the John’s form.

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Add a mouse listener to the table like this:

```
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        int row = table.rowAtPoint(event.getPoint());
        int column = table.columnAtPoint(event.getPoint());
        if (row >= 0 && column >= 0) {
            // Cell has been clicked
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it also like this:

```
...            
jTable1.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
jTable1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
   @Override
   public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
       ...
       int row = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
       int col = jTable1.getSelectedColumn());
       if (evt.getClickCount() > 1) { // double-click etc...
          ...
```